# Testing empty cells in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, is-empty

I'm creating a formula in Excel VBA of the form

```
myformula(cell1, cell2, range)
```

where the range looks something like the first 7 columns of this:

```
V1    D2    V2    D3    V3    D4    V4    RESULT
0.5   2     0.7
```

There will always be a value in the first column, which will be a value between 0 and 1 inclusive. All subsequent columns may be empty, but if there is a value in D2 there will also be a value in V2 and so on.

My formula goes in the RESULT column and involves summing the figures in the V columns but only if the preceding D column is filled. i.e. in this case it would calculate V1 + V2 but ignore V3 and V4.

The VB I have been using works with

```
if IsEmpty(D2)
```

to select the appropriate values and this works fine in most cases.

However, I also want to be able to apply this formula to cases where the V and D values are calculated by a formula. The formula is conditional, outputting either a number, or "" (something like `IF(A2="","",3)`) So the cell range looks identical but is no longer considered truly empty by VB.

I'm looking for ways to work around this. I realise that the result of a formula will never be truly empty but is there a way of making the contents of the cell "empty enough" for VB to understand it as empty? Alternatively is there a different condition I can use to pick up the empty cells - but I must be able to differentiate between zero values and empty cells.

ETA: I am struggling to implement Stepan1010's solution. This is what I'm doing - it may be wrong:

```
Public Function YEARAV(sdate As Date, edate As Date, yearrange As Range) As Variant

    Dim v1 As Variant
    Dim v2 As Variant
    Dim v3 As Variant
    Dim v4 As Variant

    Dim b As Date
    Dim c As Date
    Dim d As Date

    v1 = yearrange.Cells(1, 1)
    v2 = yearrange.Cells(1, 3)
    v3 = yearrange.Cells(1, 5)
    v4 = yearrange.Cells(1, 7)

    b = yearrange.Cells(1, 2)
    c = yearrange.Cells(1, 4)
    d = yearrange.Cells(1, 6)

    total_days = edate - sdate

    a = sdate
    e = edate

    If Range(yearrange.Cells(1, 6)).Value = vbNullString Then
        d = edate
        If Range(yearrange.Cells(1, 4)).Value = vbNullString Then
            c = edate
            If Range(yearrange.Cells(1, 2)).Value = vbNullString Then
                b = edate
            End If
        End If
    End If

    YEARAV = ((b - a) * v1 + (c - b) * v2 + (d - c) * v3 + (e - d) * v4) / total_days

End Function
```

I've also tried just using `If b = vbNullString` etc as well.

Comment: You *could* use the `Or` operator... e.g. `If IsEmpty(D2) Or D2="" Then`. Add as many Ors as you want to describe what you consider is "empty enough".

Answer (score 1):

For zero you can just check if `Range("D2").Value = 0`

To check if a formula is returning a blank you can use if `Range("D2").Value = vbNullString`

You can also normally get away with `Range("D2").Value = ""` (although some diehard vba people will probably recommend vbNullString instead)

Comment: I tried using `vbNullString` but it doesn't work with the formulae. It still works fine with the empty cells but not with those set to "". Same for using `=""`.

Comment: @apkdsmith You can also try if LEN(Range("D2").Value) = 0

Comment: @apkdsmith you cannot use vbNullString in a formula directly - that is only for VBA. - not sure if you knew that. - ISBLANK() is another one you might want to try if you are only worried about your formula.

Comment: I'm not using it in a formula directly? I'm writing a formula in VBA which I want to use it in.

Comment: It may be that I'm not implementing it properly though - I'll just edit my post to show what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @apkdsmith One of these options should work for you. Or you can use a combination of them in an if statement using OR() or AND() - in VBA or/and. Checking whether a cell is empty or blank or zero is usually not a big issue. Did you try David Zemens suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom function.  Use the function below, and you can call it like:

`Debug.Print IsCellFormulaEmpty(Range("D2"))`

Here is the Function:

```
Function IsCellFormulaEmpty(c As Range) As Boolean

Dim myVal As String
myVal = Trim(c.Value)

Select Case myVal
    Case Empty
        IsCellFormulaEmpty = True
    Case Else
        IsCellFormulaEmpty = False
End Select

End Function
```

I tested this on constant value of `6`, a formula `=IF(D24=C24,C23,"")` (which returned a null string) and a constant value of `0`.  The results are `False, True, False` as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, try to avoid VBA when you can.  In which case, given a data setup like this:

[image]

The formula in cell H2 and copied down is:

```
=A2+SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:F2<>""),--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("d",$B$1:$F$1))),C2:G2)
```